# Document class: APA6 - problem using the abstract

Tags: titles, abstract, apa6

First of all, I am a bloody beginner in LaTeX, searching for some help.

I am using the document class `APA6.cls` and I want to separate the content of title page from the abstract page. Using `\newpage` command is somehow ignored by MiKTeX. Is it even possible to separate both elements?

Greetings, 
Jens

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Write a complete example that shows your problem starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, so we understand what it's about. Preferrably it should include no extra stuff, but only the relevant parts, so in this case `\abstract`, `\maketitle` and the `\newpage` that was ignored should be in it, but there doesn't have to be any main text.

Comment: Have you tried `\clearpage` instead of `\newpage` to force a page break?

Comment: @Jens: I tried to redefine the commands `\@abstract` etc. and prepending it with an additional `\newpage`, it does not work. I come across often about `apa6` and it seems kind of being 'weirdly' setup.

Comment: Hello, thanks for helpful responses. So it's not my failure that it doesn't work. For now, I decided to use another document class, due to those restrictions (which may be good for papers, etc.; but not for modifiying the document class for a master thesis). 

If others ask: example below

\documentclass[doc]{apa6}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\affiliation{Germany}

\newpage
%\clearpage (doesn't work either)

\abstract{This cannot be on the second page}          

\begin{document}

\maketitle    

\end{document}

thanks

Comment: @Jens: `scrbook` oder `memoir` sind sicherlich eine gute Wahl ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to push this out of the unanswered queue, here's a workaround for getting the abstract in the second page. I'd never recommend `apa6` for anything else than submissions to the APA.

```
\documentclass[doc]{apa6}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\maketitle}
  {{\abstractname}}
  {\newpage\textbf{\abstractname}}% remove `\textbf` if you don't want boldface
  {}{}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\shorttitle{Title}
\author{Me}
\affiliation{Germany}
\abstract{This cannot be on the second page}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

The correct patch, however, depends on the options passed to the class. This one is good for `doc`.